# screen height sliding menu and content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a sample site that mimics Youtube current menu display in which a click of a button slides the menu in or out of view and the end result is stored in a cookie so when the user goes from one page to another they have the same menu position and visiting the site is not so annoying. I want to accomplish this with a twist, the header, body and footer must slide along with the navigator while the button is clicked. I have done a majority of the work  but i'm not so adapted to jquery

```
<body onLoad="navLoad();">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nav"> 
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="logo"></div>
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things
            Testing things

        </div>
        <div id="control">
            <button>
                &nbsp;
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <header>

        </header>
        <div id="middle">

        </div>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript I have goes as such

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
} 

function navLoad() {
var navmode = getCookie("navigator");
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var control = document.getElementById("control");
var container = document.getElementById("container");

if (navmode == null || navmode == "") {
    setCookie("navigator", "open", 90);
    navmode = "open";
}

switch(navmode) {
    default:
        nav.classList.add("visible");
        nav.style.width = "20%";
        menu.style.width = "85%";
        control.style.width = "15%";
        container.style.width = "80%";
        break;
    case "closed":
        nav.style.width = "3%";
        menu.style.width = "0%";
        menu.style.display = "none";
        control.style.width = "100%";
        container.style.width = "97%";
        break;
}
}
```

and the css for reference

```
/* SITE LOOK */
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative; 
    background: rgba(255,204,255,1);
}

#container {
    float: right;
    background: rgba(0,153,0,1);
}

nav, #menu, #control, #container{ height: 100vh; }

/* NAVIGATOR STYLE */
#nav {
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,102,255,1);
}

#menu {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

#control {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

/* HEADER STYLE */
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: rgba(51,102,0,1);
}

/* MIDDLE STYLE */
#middle {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    background: rgba(0,51,0,1);
}

/* FOOTER STYLE */
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: rgba(102,153,0,1);
}
```

Comment: Sharing a fiddle of the same would be a great idea!

Comment: dont know how to do a fiddle, let me attempt it

Comment: Yeah im not used to JSfiddle, this may be a while

Comment: Sadly I can't get the desired effect on fiddle, I may need more time afterall.

Comment: @EltonRodriguez Here's a quick fiddle with the data you've provided: http://jsfiddle.net/nVLJP/

Comment: yes I have the same result on my jsfiddle but that is not the same result I have on my browser. I cant shape it back to how i originally had it. This is frustrating how I had it set nicely on my screen but fiddle is not helping me.

Comment: @EltonRodriguez Is this more like what you were expecting? http://jsfiddle.net/nVLJP/1/

Comment: @Renson yep, thats exactly it except the container is not showing. I think it's getting there

Comment: @EltonRodriguez That's because there isn't a set height and there's nothing in the #content. Just add some words or a <p> to it and it should show up

Comment: Here's fiddle with the content showing by making the content `width: 80%; float: left;` and nav `width: 20%`  http://jsfiddle.net/nVLJP/2/

Comment: that is a close replica, except the nav is over the height it should be. Close enough I suppose. what im trying to do is get the blue section of the map to slide left to hide and right to show when clicking on the button provided. that and record the position in a cookie in order to remember how the user left it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really recommend using jQuery and the [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/), which can really simplify things.

Without jquery, you can just say
    HTML

```
 <button onclick="reSize()" />
```

Javascript

```
function reSize() {
    setTimeout(reSize,500);
    //Add Script for Resizing here (same for when cookie is closed)
    //Add Script for setCookie() here
}
```

This should set the animation to run when you click the button and the change will take 500 milliseconds (change this number to whatever speed you'd like).

This can also be accomplished by jquery using:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
      $('#nav').click( function() {
           $('#nav').animate( { width: 0 }, 500);
           $('#container').animate( { width: '100%' }, 500);
      });
});
```

Both methods should have the `#container` and `#nav` resize simultaneously, although there may be stacking issues depending on how you set the page up.

Neither of the scripts here account for toggling, unfortunately, but this can easily be accomplished by adding a class to `#nav` (something like open/closed or active/inactive) and then running an if/then statement off of which class is currently active.

Comment: addClass you mean? I was wondering how to do that in jquery. I know that with a class I can manage to use it as a base on whether or not the nav should be open upon load, likewise with the button click event. How would it look like to add a class in jquery?

Comment: @EltonRodriguez In jquery it's just `$(object).addClass('class')`. Multiple classes can be added simply by `.addClass('class1 class2')` and they can be removed with `.removeClass('class')`. Putting `.removeClass()` with a blank will remove all classes. Finally, there is also a `.toggleClass('class')` function that you could use in this situation, which will toggle a class on or off.

Comment: Thank you and I know it in JQuery but I decided it best to use js over jquery because I really am not sure what code to use to do what I succeeded in doing on my own so far. The only thing I want to know is how to slide left and right with javascript now but im trying my best to investigate with the logic

Comment: Well to slide left and right with a absolute element, just simply change `left:`

Comment: wait using [code]left:[/code] will slide it? can you give me an example using the reSize funtion example? I have something already working using that example, however I don't understand how to make it go left and right with [code]left:[/code]. and yes I understand you mean the css [code]left:[/code] im just unsure how to use it to slide it.